# Does using System.Enum as a variable type have a downside compared to using a direct reference to the enum?

Tags: c#, enums

Im working on a game with RPG elements, and am currently doing an ability system. While trying to figure out how I want it to work I stumbled on System.Enum, something I havent used before but it seems very powerful to be able to store any enum I want. I was wondering if it has a downside? Does the compiler still do a cast or something behind the scenes to figure out what type of enum it is? Dont know how to figure it out by myself and had a hard time finding an answer, or atleast one I could understand.

```
public class TestingStuff
{
    private void ExampleOne()
    {
        System.Enum anyEnum = Vehicle.Car;
        switch (anyEnum)
        {
            case Vehicle.Car:
                //do stuff
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ExampleTwo()
    {
        Vehicle thisEnum = Vehicle.Car;
        switch (thisEnum)
        {
            case Vehicle.Car:
                //do stuff
                break;
        }
    }

    private enum Vehicle
    {
        Car
    }
}
```

So in this example, would ExampleOne() and ExampleTwo() perform the same way? In the game I will have multiple AI characters that would have to do multiple ability checks in this manner to see what ability best suits the situation. I dont expect to reach more than maybe 10-20 of these calls in any single frame so I dont think its an issue either way, but it still got me curious and I would like to learn more.

Comment: [`System.Enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum?view=net-8.0) is an abstract base class -- i.e. a reference type.  So when you do `Enum anyEnum = Vehicle.Car;` you are boxing the enum in the same way you would if you did `object myEnum = Vehicle.Car;`  That's going to give you a small performance penalty, see maybe [Do boxing and unboxing has the same performance hit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9555024) and [How is it that an enum derives from System.Enum and is an integer at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4626394).  Do those two questions answer yours?

Comment: See also [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide): Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing#performance): *In relation to simple assignments, boxing and unboxing are computationally expensive processes.*  That being said, the actual performance penalty might be minuscule compared to whatever else your code is doing.

Comment: Try creating a different enum, assign its first value to your anyEnum variable and check what the (unchanged) switch does

Comment: Anyway, why do you need to switch on the abstract `Enum` type?  Are you trying to create a switch statement with cases whose values are actually different enum types?  Because from the example shown in your question, boxing your enum values to `System.Enum` seems unnecessary.

Comment: @dbc Boxing/unboxing actually explained a lot I think, so thanks a ton! Ive heard the term of boxes before but never understood its meaning and actually thought it was aimed towards more low level languages than C#, didnt know it was just a general programming concept. Thanks a lot! Best answer!

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Dont really know the reason for this.  But I still did what you asked, and the case wasnt reached. I would like to know if I missed something?

Comment: @dbc and also to explain my thought process for maybe using System.Enum:
I want to make a different enum for every RPG-class abilities, like WarriorEnum, MageEnum, etc, to make the code more readable for myself. And it would be cool if I could have just a generic ability struct or something that could contain different enums. Then they would be passed to different switches depending on the RPG-class, again to make it more readable so I dont end up with a single switch statement with potentially hundreds of cases. I want to contain every RPG-class to its own enum and its own switch

Comment: Well with C# 7 and later you can switch on Enum type + value, e.g. `switch (anyEnum) { case Vehicle v when v == Vehicle.Car: { /* Do stuff */ } break; }`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299001) to [Is there a better alternative than this to 'switch on type'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/298976).

Comment: @MissingTime I expected that the match would be on underlying int value, so that a different enum with the same int value would also match. I finally got around to testing it myself and it appears I was wrong (as you already found) - it correctly keeps its type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting to `System.Enum` causes a boxing operation (as pointed out in the comments) which has a slight overhead and can mess with comparison operations-- two boxed values of `Vehicle.Car`, for example, could evaluate to false, because the boxed objects are different references.

```
Enum a = Vehicle.Car;
Enum b = Vehicle.Car;
Console.WriteLine(a == b); //outputs False
```

If you want to have an efficient way to store any enum, you can use an int, which costs [no overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823132/is-casting-enum-to-int-expensive). This is because enums are actually stored as integers under the covers by default (they can also be stored as [longs or other types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7093457/2791540) if you choose to).

```
private void ExampleThree()
{
    int thisEnum = (int)Vehicle.Car;
    switch ((Vehicle)thisEnum)
    {
        case Vehicle.Car:
            //do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

Be warned though. Some consider overuse of enums a [code smell](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/300080/when-are-enums-not-a-code-smell).

Comment: Okay, this actually seems like a SUPER simple and useful way of doing this. I actually thought about using just pure ints like ID-numbers from the start but decided against it becuase it felt like it would become so unreadable to just have a bunch of numbers everywhere. But this seems to be the best of two worlds. Will most likely go with this solution, thanks a lot! Will tattoo ExampleThree all over my project

Comment: Enums don't have to be `int`, they can be other [numeric types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) including `long` or `ulong` as well.  So if you want to store an enum in a numeric value you need to use one of those.